# PHP - How to write a code patcher for PHP app in PHP?

Tags: php, updates

I manage a public-domain PHP app that we have customized in-house. It can use a lot of plugins/etc that are written by other people. All of these get updates available.

Is it possible to write an independent patching utility that re-integrates our customization code after the core app and plugins/etc have been updated? If yes, what could be a good solution? I am perfectly okay with maintaining the customization code blocks alone in a separate location for this "tool" to find and use.

Comment: *"Is it possible?"* - Probably so, yes. Is it the best way to go? Probably not. I'd look at what VCSs do to facilitate automatic merging; and then realise that 100% automated merging is virtually impossible and a human will always have to look at the result.

Comment: Consider using modules as separated packages and allow them to override your methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few alternate ways to achieve this:

- Traditional: You can use the GNU `diff`/`patch` utilities to create a patch file with the differences between your customized version and the vanilla version, install the updates and then apply the patch to the now updated one.
- Inheritance: Assuming the app is using an OOP paradigm, rather than modifying the core app classes, you could extend the classes with your own, that way your customizations can be kept segregated from the core files so when you update the app, the core will be updated and your customizations left untouched
- Caching: You could implement a functionality similar to OpenCart's [vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod) that merges your customizations into the core software by creating dynamically merged versions as cached `.php` files which are ran instead of the original core ones, this way you can run an altered core without changing the original.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer. Based on these three replies and plenty more we got from other sources, we decided to implement Source Control based diff/patching. It is not a 100% automatic, yes (thats' ideal) but it lets us do it far more cheaply than doing it completely by hand.